# sort list of files by date in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, datetime

Given a text file containing some list of files, e.g.

```
$ cat file_list.txt
/var/x/file1.txt
/var/y/file2.txt
<etc>
```

How can I sort this list of files by some criteria - like their last accessed time, or last changed time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `stat` command with `sort` like this:

```
while read -r line; do
   stat -c '%Y %n' "$line"
done < file_list.txt | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

- `stat -c '%Y %n'` lists **time of last modification, seconds since Epoch** followed by a space and file name
- `sort -n` sorts timestamps and their filename numerically
- `cut -d ' ' -f2` prints only file names from sort's output

Comment: On OSX (BSD) the equivalent stat command is `stat -f '%m %N' "$line"`.

Answer (score 4):

Try one liner (by modification time):

```
ls -t $(cat file_list.txt)
```

OR

```
ls -t `cat file_list.txt`
```

Comment: This will fail if any file contains spaces. Also, this is subject to pathname expansion. To be “safe”: `(set -f; IFS=$'\n'; ls -t $(cat file_list.txt))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most recently changed file with

```
cat file_list.txt | xargs stat -c '%Y %n' | sort | tail -1 | cut -c 12-
```

You can get the most recent timestamp with

```
cat file_list.txt | xargs stat -c '%Y %n' | sort | tail -1 | cut -c -10
```